# Subtracting row means for columns with numeric data

Tags: r, row, mean

I have a csv file with large data, e.g.

```
> data <- read.csv("data2006.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
> data
      cntry      aa      ab      ac      ad 
1        AT       3       4       3       2 
2        AT       1       2       3       2   
3        AT       2       3       3       4
```

I want to demean this data, i.e. to subtract the mean of each row from all elements of subsequent raws. I need to do it for elements contained in the columns with numeric values, i.e. the columns 'aa', 'ab', 'ac' and 'ad', while preserving the elements in the column 'cntry'. So, the desired outcome looks like:

```
      cntry      aa      ab      ac      ad 
1        AT       0       1       0      -1 
2        AT      -1       0       1       0   
3        AT      -1       0       0       1
```

In the article on mean-centering (http://www.gastonsanchez.com/visually-enforced/how-to/2014/01/15/Center-data-in-R/) I've found that one can use rowMeans for that:

```
center_rowmeans <- function(x) {
xcenter = rowMeans(x)
x - rep(xcenter, rep.int(nrow(x), ncol(x)))
}
```

but I cannot adjust this code to using for processing my data. Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really are missing is how to identify the class of a column and index with that identification:

```
anatasia <- read.table(text="      cntry      aa      ab      ac      ad 
1        AT       3       4       3       2 
                       2        AT       1       2       3       2   
                       3        AT       2       3       3       4 ")


rmeans <- rowMeans(anatasia[,sapply(anatasia, class) %in% c("numeric", "integer")])

dat  <- cbind(anatasia[,!sapply(anatasia, class) %in% c("numeric", "integer")],
              anatasia[, sapply(anatasia, class) %in% c("numeric", "integer")]-rmeans)

colnames(dat) <- colnames(anatasia)
dat
```

> ```
>   cntry aa ab ac ad
> 1    AT  0  1  0 -1
> 2    AT -1  0  1  0
> 3    AT -1  0  0  1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
numcols <- sapply(df,is.numeric)
df[numcols] <- df[numcols] - rowMeans(df[numcols])
#   cntry aa ab ac ad
# 1    AT  0  1  0 -1
# 2    AT -1  0  1  0
# 3    AT -1  0  0  1
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="cntry      aa      ab      ac      ad 
AT       3       4       3       2 
AT       1       2       3       2   
AT       2       3       3       4",strin=F,h=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you've assigned a function to the variable center_rowmeans. This means you can now call apply or lapply over your dataframe to return the output you want.

Using purrr:

```
data %>% map(center_rowmeans)
```

Base R:

```
data[2:5] <- lapply(data[2:5], center_rowmeans)
```